# pyqt5, matplotlib2 and the deprecation of axes.hold

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

Based on demo code from https://gist.github.com/pklaus/3e16982d952969eb8a9a for embedding matplotlib graphs into a qt GUI I have the following code:

```
# https://gist.github.com/pklaus/3e16982d952969eb8a9a
class MatplotlibCanvas(FigureCanvas):

    """Ultimately, this is a QWidget (as well as a FigureCanvasAgg, etc.)."""
    def __init__(self, mystacker, spectrum_id, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        self.stacker = mystacker
        self.spectrum_id = spectrum_id

        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        # We want the axes cleared every time plot() is called
        self.axes.hold(False)

        self.compute_initial_figure()

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        spectrumplot.plot_spectrum(self.stacker, self.spectrum_id, self.axes)
```

But with the new matplotlib version 2, I get the following warning:

`MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: axes.hold is deprecated.
    See the API Changes document (http://matplotlib.org/api/api_changes.html) for more details.`

http://matplotlib.org/api/api_changes.html says

> The ‘hold’ keyword argument and all functions and methods related to
>   it are deprecated, along with the ‘axes.hold’ rcParams entry. The
>   behavior will remain consistent with the default hold=True state that
>   has long been in place. Instead of using a function or keyword
>   argument (hold=False) to change that behavior, explicitly clear the
>   axes or figure as needed prior to subsequent plotting commands.

**What would be the proper calls to "explicitly clear the axes or figure as needed" in my case?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the code shown it is not clear, at which point you would actually need `hold(False)`.

What the documentation says is that you should clear the axes explicitely if you need to instead of relying on some automatic clearance. I.e. use `self.axes.clear()` at any point you like to clear the axes and remove its content. Whether you actually need to clear the axes depends on your usage case. 
Usually updating the artists in an axes is a much cleaner way than clearing the axes and recreating the artists.

(You may want to update your question to include more information about what exactly you are doing, for someone to jugde at which point you would need that.)

Comment: I just assumed that the `hold(False)` was required for the graph to properly redraw when it is resized. But as it turns out, it works as expected (with recreating the axis and choosing appropriate tick marks) without the `hold(False)`. I will leave it out for the time being, and introduce a `self.axes.clear()` if I should run into any problems with that.

Comment: What is used now instead of hold?