# PyQt4/matplotlib:How to fix MatplotlibDeprecationWarning due to axes.hold()

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt4

I am using matplotlib with python3.6.My program runs successfully but it shows the following warning message:

/home/sree/python/PyPrgm.py:41:MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:axes.hold is deprecated.

I referenced http://matplotlib.org/api/api_changes.html. How can I get rid of this warning ?

```
class PyTabWidget(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PyTabWidget,self).__init__()
        tab1=FirstTab()
        self.addTab(tab1,"TAB1")

class FirstTab(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FirstTab,self).__init__()
        grp1=QGroupBox("GroupBox1")
        grp1.setStyleSheet("QGroupBox { border:1px ; background-color:white}")
        graph=TwoD_GraphWindow()    #2D graphWindow object
        layout=QGridLayout()    #create layout
        layout.setColumnMinimumWidth(0, 10)
        layout.setColumnMinimumWidth(2, 10)
        layout.setColumnMinimumWidth(4, 10)
        layout.setRowMinimumHeight(0, 10)
        layout.setRowMinimumHeight(4, 10)
        layout.addWidget(graph, 2, 2)
        self.setLayout(layout)  #set the layout
        A=np.linspace(0,10,100)
        graph.DrawGraph(A)  #invoke DrawGraph() function

class TwoD_GraphWindow(FigureCanvas): #Class for 2D window
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig=Figure() #Figure() object
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig) #creating FigureCanvas
        self.setWindowTitle("Main") # sets Window title

    def DrawGraph(self, x):#Fun for Graph plotting
        self.axes.clear() #clear the axes
        self.axes.plot(x,np.sin(x),'-' ) #plots the 2D graph
        self.axes.hold(True) #do not clear the axis
        self.axes.plot(x,np.cos(x),'--');
        self.draw()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyqt5, matplotlib2 and the deprecation of axes.hold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42155430/pyqt5-matplotlib2-and-the-deprecation-of-axes-hold)

Answer (score 3):

The documentation says that `Axes.hold()` now is always set to `true` by default, so you can successfully remove this line of code:
`self.axes.hold(True)` and be happy.

[Check out the Docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hold.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.hold)

Comment: "...and be happy" is the important part here!